# Understanding OR in variable PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I've been using this package `brain/nonces` for nonce verification in WordPress, while digging into the code I've found this line `$context or $context = new RequestGlobalsContext();` and I cant understand what it means. It would be helpful if someone can explain more on this.

Here is the full code,

```
 public function validate(NonceContextInterface $context = null)
    {
        $context or $context = new RequestGlobalsContext();

        $value = $context->offsetExists($this->action) ? $context[$this->action] : '';
        if (!$value || !is_string($value)) {
            return false;
        }

        $lifeFilter = $this->lifeFilter();

        add_filter('nonce_life', $lifeFilter);
        $valid = wp_verify_nonce($value, $this->hashedAction());
        remove_filter('nonce_life', $lifeFilter);

        return (bool)$valid;
    }
```

Comment: If $context already exists, use it; otherwise create it again. The same as `$context || $context = new Class();`

Comment: Essentially it's checking if $context is `null`, if it is null, then instantiate the global context provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just means that if `$context` has a value that can be interpreted as `true`, that part after `or` won't be executed. In this particular case I guess it's just a quick way to place default value in `$context`, in case if function was called without specifying it.

Comment: Correct, it's the same as `if (!$context) { $context = new RequestGlobalsContext(); }`

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not evaluate the 2 subexpression of an OR if the first subexpression is true. This one

```
$context or $context = new RequestGlobalsContext();
```

can be written for better understanding as

```
if (! $context) $context = new RequestGlobalsContext();
```

The speed differences between the two variants are practically irrelevant.